# How To Add a Class to Prev/Next on Wordpress Pagination? (paginate_links)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I modified my Wordpress functions.php to show a pagination:

```
<?php echo paginate_links( array(
    'prev_text'          => __('Previous Page'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next Page'),
    'type'               => 'list'
) ); ?>
```

The output is nearly perfect:

```
<ul class="page-numbers">
    <li>
        <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://domain.tld/page/2/">2</a>
    </li>
    …
    <li>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://domain.tld/page/10/">10</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="https://domain.tld/page/2/">Next Page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to add a class to the `Prev` and `Next` list item `li`?

```
    <li class="prev-list-item">
        <a class="prev page-numbers" href="http://domain.tld/page/1/">Previous Page</a>
    </li>
```

&

```
    <li class="next-list-item">
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://domain.tld/page/2/">Next Page</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: The function [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) don't provide a filter hook for this. Look [at the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L0) at line 3156, it wraps all links in `<li></li>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of having the function output directly, you could have the list of links returned as an array. You can then target the next and previous links with their own respective functions.

```
$links = paginate_links( array(
  'prev_next'          => false,
  'type'               => 'array'
) );

if ( $links ) :

    echo '<ul class="page-numbers">';

    // get_previous_posts_link will return a string or void if no link is set.
    if ( $prev_posts_link = get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Previous Page' ) ) ) :
        echo '<li class="prev-list-item">';
        echo $prev_posts_link;
        echo '</li>';
    endif;

    echo '<li>';
    echo join( '</li><li>', $links );
    echo '</li>';

    // get_next_posts_link will return a string or void if no link is set.
    if ( $next_posts_link = get_next_posts_link( __( 'Next Page' ) ) ) :
        echo '<li class="next-list-item">';
        echo $next_posts_link;
        echo '</li>';
    endif;
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript (jQuery) solution. Not nice, but it works:

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 
  $('ul.page-numbers li a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.hasClass('prev') ) $this.parent('li').addClass('prev-list-item');
    if ( $this.hasClass('next') ) $this.parent('li').addClass('next-list-item');      
  });
 
}( jQuery ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="page-numbers">
    <li>
        <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://domain.tld/page/2/">2</a>
    </li>
    …
    <li>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://domain.tld/page/10/">10</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="https://domain.tld/page/2/">Next Page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just wrap the javascript code in `<script></script>`tags and insert it nearby after the `paginate_links()`function.

Comment: As I try to avoid JavaScript where possible and do not have jQuery implemented, this solution does not meet my needs. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: You can try `type: 'array'` - Returns an array of the paginated link list to offer full control of display. (Oops, this solution is used in the accepted answer, not seen )